# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.ext'

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I've created an AngularJS app served by *node.js* and now I've been asked to move from that to *python flask*. I encountered some errors and after search I was informed I have to include *flask.ext.triangle* but when I try to access *localhost:5000* I get this error:

> flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "server", an ImportError was
>   raised: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.ext'

I have installed *flask-triangle* using pip. My *server.py* is this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.triangle import Triangle

app = Flask(__name__)
Triangle(app)

@app.route('/')
def mainPage():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

Before importing triangle I got errors regarding AngularJS filters. All the routing and utility is handled by AngularJS, I just want flask to serve my app.

Comment: Useless answers regarding my issue, as you can see by the answer at my question neither of the two posts you tagged contain it.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't get *triangle* to work so I found another way to make things happen. Found out that if you change the *AngularJS expression brackets* to something else and you forget completely about *triangle* the page loads. Here is my configuration on *AngularJS app.js*:

```
.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//').endSymbol('//');
});
```

Now all I had to do is go to my *HTML* files and change *{{ }}* to *// //*.

**EDIT:**

Found the most proper way to do it. Instead of using *render_template* and have to mess with *Jinja* I used *current_app.send_static_file* to serve my *HTML* and faced no problems at all. My updated *server.py*:

```
from flask import Flask, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def mainPage():
    return current_app.send_static_file('main.html')
```

Everything else is handled by *AngularJS*, no need to configure expression delimiters, used the built-in *{{ }}*.

Comment: ~~flask.ext.triangle~~ `flask_triangle`